# How to rewrite these LINQ statements into one query

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to use one LINQ query to do the same?

```
var ints = new []{1,2,3,4,5};
var odd = from i in ints where i%2==1 select i;
var even = from i in ints where i%2==0 select i;
var q = from s in new[]{""} 
    select new {oddCount = odd.Count(), evenCount = even.Count()};

Console.Write(q);
```

**Edit**: Want to get this

[image]

Comment: You could do it with `GroupBy`.

Comment: for `q`, you don't even use `s`, so why not just `var q = new {oddCount = odd.Count(), evenCount = even.Count()};`?

Comment: Also, what do you expect from `Console.Write(q);`?

Comment: Why would you want to combine them into one single query? It feels like a strange use of Linq to iterate over a static one element collection and not even use the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect candidate for [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var info = ints.Aggregate(
    new { oddCount = 0, evenCount = 0 }, (a, i) =>
    new { oddCount = a.oddCount + (i & 1), evenCount = a.evenCount + ((i & 1) ^ 1) });

Console.WriteLine(info);
```

prints

```
{ oddCount = 3, evenCount = 2 }
```

Answer (score 4):

`Count()` already allows you to specify a predicate. So you can combine the above in one linq like this:

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Console.Write($"Odd={ints.Count(i => i % 2 == 1)}, Even={ints.Count(i => i % 2 == 0)}");
```

Also note that it will be considerably faster than doing a `Where()` as *counting* is easier to perform than actually returning matching elements.

### Edit

If all you want is a single linq query, you could do the following clever trick:

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var Odd = ints.Count(i => i % 2 == 1);
Console.Write($"Odd={Odd}, Even={ints.Length - Odd}");
```

Comment: Why the `from s in new[] {""}...` ? that's returing a 1 item enumerable of the anonymous type.  does `q.oddCount` even compile?

Comment: @JohnBoker: You're right. I updated my code. I guess he was trying to (incorrectly) create an anonymous object with two properties.

Comment: Technically that's still two Linq queries.

Comment: @juharr: You're right too. I have added a one-linq version.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it one query like this:

```
var q = ints.Select(i => new { Number = i, Type = (i % 2 == 0) ? "Even" : "Odd" }).GroupBy(i => i.Type).Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

This would return a list though, with 'Type' and 'Count', as shown below.

[image]

If you're looking for a simple object as you currently have, you can use something simpler like this:

```
var q = new { OddCount = ints.Count(i => i % 2 != 0), EvenCount = ints.Count(i => i % 2 == 0) };
```

[image]

This would be a single object with "OddCount" and "EventCount" properties.

Comment: The results of your two different methods do not agree.

Comment: @recursive Indeed.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that does only a single iteration over the original list.

```
var ints = new []{1,2,3,4,5};
string[] parities = { "even", "odd" };

var result = ints
    .GroupBy(i => i % 2)
    .Select(g => new { Name = parities[g.Key], Count = g.Count() });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just move your queries directly into the select

```
var q = from s in new[] { "" }   
    select new {
        oddCount = (from i in ints where i % 2 == 1 select i).Count(), 
        evenCount = (from i in ints where i % 2 == 0 select i).Count()};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int odd = 0;
int even = 0;

(from s in ints
        let evens = s % 2 == 0 ? even++ : even
        let odds = s % 2 != 0 ? odd++ : odd
        select true).ToList();
```

With this you have the values loaded in even and odd.

This approach has the advantage it only iterates the array once